# Tool for plotting a function with complex terms

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm searching for a tool that can plot a function like below with output in a complex plane:
$$z(t)=t\cdot e^ \frac {i\cdot t} \pi  $$
with
$$ z: \mathbb R \to \mathbb C  $$
$$t \in \mathbb R$$
Does anyone have recommendations?

Comment: Any program that can plot parametric functions would work, as long as it can do complex number calculations. Mathematica, a combination python/numpy/matplotlib, or even Excel can be used for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use python, with numpy and matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(-50, 50, 1000)
z = t*np.exp(np.complex(0, 1)*t/np.pi)

plt.plot(z.real,z.imag)
plt.show()
```

[image]